# Writing crossplatform Java Console application

Tags: java, console, native

I have practical task to write Java application with native console behavior working for multiple platforms. 
I've managed to detect platform and environment software is opened in just fine.

I use Netbeans native packaging to create package with consoleapp binary for each platform.

```
public class ConnTrol {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Console c = System.console();
        if (c == null) {
            if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Linux")) {
                try {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"konsole","--noclose","-e",AppPath.getPath()+"/../consoleapp"});
                } catch (IOException ex) {

                }
            } else if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
                try {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd","/c","start",AppPath.getPath()+"\\..\\consoleapp.exe"});
                } catch (IOException ex) {

                }
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }

        c.printf("Hello world!%n");
    }

}
```

Extended version checks for different console versions on *nix systems.

The tricky part as I see is to let this work on Windows.
The problem is "consoleapp.exe" created on Windows is always Windows Application (not a Console Application), so if application is not running in console and trying run its copy in console, the I/O's of that copy also are not connected to calling console, and application ends up in dead loop restarting itself.

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: What is the specific question?

Comment: How I make this work on Windows? :)

Comment: Why not to use System.out.println?

Comment: As an option- yes, but it does not solve the problem. The problem is on Windows Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd","/c","start",AppPath.getPath()+"\\..\\consoleapp.exe"}); does not connect streams of consoleapp.exe to cmd, so new copy also runs out of console. It's because Netbeans always make GUI binary, and GUI binaries on Windows never attached to console even if they are launched from. I seek how to workaround this problem.

Comment: Looking deep into cmd construction, it sounds like cmd is the problem, since it seems to ignore I/Os of the started application once it marked as GUI app